# Can array type replace straightly sequence type?

Tags: f#, sequence

The code below works.

```
Seq.iter (printfn "%d") [|1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10|]
```

Here is another example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340408.aspx

Can array type replace straightly sequence type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because the array is implicitly converted to a `seq<'T>` (one of the few spots where this sort of conversion happens).

However, some of the `Seq` functions are not optimised for arrays and will perform slower than the equivalent `Array.x` functions.  As a result, you should use which ever module matches with the input (`List.x` for `Lists` `Array.x` for `Arrays` etc).  Also, the return type will be different - if you use `Seq.map` on an array, a `Seq` is returned rather than an `Array` which may have performance implications (for example getting the nth element is significantly faster for arrays).

Comment: +1 Aside, while the recommendation to use function matching the input makes a good sense, I generally use `Seq.xyz` functions by default (they provide more functionality and are lazy) and only use others when there is a good reason (i.e. I care about performance or want functional-list style processing).

Comment: @TomasPetricek, when you use `Seq.functionName` by default, don't you need to often cast back to the original type by calling `Seq.toWhatever`?  Can this casting become expensive if the sequences are long?  I'm still reading `RWFP`, so if the answer is explained somewhere in the book, feel free to tell me so.